# LocalDateTime to Mysql DATETIME converts actual date to actual date+5.30

Tags: java, mysql, jackson, mysql-connector

I am having a model with multiple member variables in that:
One with LocalDateTime type.

```
@Column(name = "localdatetime_field")
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
```

Other with timestamp:

```
@Column(name = "timestamp_field")
private Timestamp addedAt;
```

The problem is:

> When I save data in the DB, with mysql-connector v8.0.18:
> -> It keeps the data of Localdatetime & Timestamp same as given.
>
> with mysql-connector v5.1.34:
> -> It changes the data of Localdatetime by +5.30.

I wonder is it because of mysql-connector or some jackson convertor working behind the scenes.

Comment: What's the question? Why does that happen, or how to avoid it, or what? What are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

### Not a moment

The [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class is appropriate only to database columns of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. These types *do not represent a moment*, cannot be a point on the timeline. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, we cannot know if noon on the 23rd is noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Toulouse France, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three different moments, several hours apart.

In the context of most business app, these types are not usually appropriate. If recording when something has happened, these are the wrong types. These types are only good for (a) describing something across all time zones such as when Christmas starts (different moments in various time zones), and (b) booking appointments in the future that should remain at a certain wall-clock time even if politicians change the time zone rules in than region (Ex: dental appointment at 3 PM should stay at 3 PM even if politicians push the clock forward or backward an hour).

### A moment

For database columns of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, we would use either [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Oddly, the JDBC 4.2 spec requires support only for the second of those three: [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing to the database:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

If you want to see the returned `OffsetDateTime` in the time zone of your choice, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Be sure to use a [real time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region`. Never use 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as `IST`, `EST`, and such.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

## Beware of middleware

Unfortunately, middleware and tooling often feels the need to inject a time zone adjustment into your date-time info. Most databases store a moment as UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds). Yet some tooling will retrieve that UTC value, apply a time zone adjustment, and then report the result. This anti-feature clouds the picture of what was actually stored in the database.

To get around that anti-feature, you will need to study the documentation for your particular middleware or tool. You may be able to shut off the adjustment. Or as a workaround, you may need to set its applied time zone to be UTC/GMT, or in a pinch use the zone `Atlantic/Reykjavik` which happens to use zero as its offset.

If doing straight JDBC with the *java.time* classes, I expect you will see no such rude injection of time zone. At least I have not heard of any such behavior with any JDBC driver yet.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborative answer. I have checked this out and saw that it's happening because of the older version of mysql connector(java/v5.1.24). I assume there has been some change in the way these classes java.time.LocalDateTime values are interpreted in connector v8.x.x. Can you point me to any doc and give some details on that as to interpret why in older version an offset of +5.30 is being added to LocalDateTime.

Comment: @Hunda I don’t use MySQL; my databases of choice are Postgres & H2.  So I cannot help you further with specifics of *Connector/J*. Indeed, let me ask you: Do you have a link to documentation saying the driver was making that zone adjustment? I’ve not yet heard of a JDBC driver having that anti-feature. So I’m curious to know if any such product shipped, even if they later removed the anti-feature to properly deliver the value as stored.